# How to run podman commands on host from within container

Tags: docker, containers, rhel, podman

In case of docker, this can be achieved by mounting docker.sock inside container.

But since there is no daemon in podman. What's the replacement for docker.sock?

I want to typically check the podman images presents on host and start a new container.

I'm using Podman with --privileged=true and root.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new API (status: experimental) that was announced in a [blog post](https://podman.io/blogs/2020/01/17/podman-new-api.html) in January 2020.

```
[root@fedora31 ~]# podman --version
podman version 1.8.0
[root@fedora31 ~]# podman system service --timeout 500000 unix://root/foobar.sock 
This function is EXPERIMENTAL.
```

As the API is still experimental this might change but right now you could make a query like this:

```
[root@fedora31 ~]# curl -s --unix-socket /root/foobar.sock http://d/v1.24/images/json | python3 -m json.tool
[
    {
        "Containers": 0,
        "Created": 1572319417,
        "Id": "f0858ad3febdf45bb2e5501cb459affffacef081f79eaa436085c3b6d9bd46ca",
        "Labels": {
            "maintainer": "Clement Verna <cverna@fedoraproject.org>"
        },
        "ParentId": "",
        "RepoDigests": [
            "sha256:8fa60b88e2a7eac8460b9c0104b877f1aa0cea7fbc03c701b7e545dacccfb433"
        ],
        "RepoTags": [
            "docker.io/library/fedora:latest"
        ],
        "SharedSize": 0,
        "Size": 201095865,
        "VirtualSize": 201095865,
        "CreatedTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    null
]
[root@fedora31 ~]#
```

The command `python3 -m json.tool` was added to pretty-print the JSON output.

I think the UNIX socket can be accessed from inside a container by using the bind-mounting technique (that was mentioned in the question).

According to the [man page](https://github.com/containers/libpod/blob/master/docs/source/markdown/podman-system-service.1.md), the command `podman system service` also accepts the flag `--varlink`.

Using Varlink instead of the new API might be a better solution right now as it is more mature but it will be deprecated in the future.